# Why does codecvt_utf8_utf16::do_max_length() return 6 in MSVC2017?

Tags: c++, utf-8, utf-16

Why does Visual C++ 2017 implementation of std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<>::do_max_length() returns 6 (assuming codecvt_mode is 0)?

```
        // CLASS codecvt_utf8_utf16
template<class _Elem,
    unsigned long _Mymax = 0x10ffff,
    codecvt_mode _Mymode = (codecvt_mode)0>
    class codecvt_utf8_utf16
    : public codecvt<_Elem, char, _Statype>
    {   // facet for converting between UTF-16 _Elem and UTF-8 byte sequences

    // ...

    virtual int __CLR_OR_THIS_CALL do_max_length() const _THROW0()
        {   // return maximum length required for a conversion
        return ((_Mymode & consume_header) != 0 ? 9 // header + max input
            : (_Mymode & generate_header) != 0 ? 7  // header + max output
            : 6);   // 6-byte max input sequence, no 3-byte header
        }
```

Shouldn't it be 4 instead (to encode any Unicode code point in UTF-8 at most 4 bytes are required)?

Comment: There was a version of UTF-8 which could use up to 6 bytes for encoding a code point. Maybe Microsoft uses that for some reason. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Comment: It will also handle the case where the input stream contains an invalid codepoint (> U+10FFFF).  And then slurp more than 4 bytes, as promised.  It has to, it can't leave the stream in an inconsistent state.  But will not intentionally generate an invalid codepoint, that's why it returns 7.

Comment: @HansPassant What do you mean by "stream" - C++ I/O streams or character input sequence for the codecvt do_in/do_out methods? When input of do_in/do_out contains an invalid codepoint they are supposed to return `result::error` and not skip/ignore the invalid data.